# How to resolve permission errors while installing AWS SAM local on Ubuntu 16.04 using Jenkins user?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nodes, serverless, sam

I am trying to install AWS SAM local on Ubuntu 16.04

I am getting the following error while trying to install using jenkins user

npm install -g aws-sam-local

[image]

Note : AWS SAM local is successfully installed on root user.But getting error while trying it through Jenkins user

I have already tried the following commands for the same.

npm config set unsafe -perm=true

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10

ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

npm install -g go-npm

Please help me to sort it out?

Comment: `sudo npm install -g ...`

Comment: I have already tried this

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, install in same order.

```
sudo npm install -g go-npm
sudo npm config set unsafe-perm=true
sudo npm install -g aws-sam-local
sam --version
```